# "a moderator reviewed your flag ..." declined! Why?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, declined-flags

I had flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37798930/2142994) as "not an answer". It was declined,

[image]

Firstly, why does it say "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"? Whereas I see a comment:

[image]

Secondly, Shouldn't that be a comment? It doesn't answer the question.

**Edit:** [Why isn't it deleted already?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12705663)

---

**Update:**

The tagged answer doesn't even lead the OP to the answer. And the answer is now deleted.

Comment: If you were asked to look at that question, and you didn't know PHP, but you *did* roughly know how RESTful servers worked, would you be able to reasonably say that it was at least an *attempt* at an answer?

Comment: @Makoto Its not an _attempt_, he is just telling what would happen, not how to fix it.

Comment: Explaining the "why" is a proper answer on a Q+A site.  Use a forum if you only ever want to see "how" answers.  It is not a good "why" answer, use your vote to do something about it.  Expecting the moderators to be a proxy for not having enough rep is going to be disappointing.

Comment: @HansPassant ok, How is it that the answer is not deleted after so many ["Recommended deletions"](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12705663)?

Comment: Surely you know by now, the mod disagreed.  Finding 5 people that also can't vote to delete is not difficult btw, none of these users are close.  Get 20K rep and you no longer need to depend on the kindness and battle-hardened wisdom of strangers.

Comment: @AniMenon It takes 6 "Recommend Deletion" or 3 "Delete" votes to delete the answer from the Very Low Quality queue. And as said in the linked post, this is an answer so the flag was rightfully declined.

Comment: @Tunaki Its deleted now, so solved.

Comment: @AniMenon Because 3 users with the delete answers privilege decided that way. But note that this does not imply that flagging as NAA was correct.

Comment: @Tunaki It didn't answer the question. At least that's what I felt. Even if you call it a "try" my tag might be wrong but it certainly was a bad(low-quality) answer and hence got deleted.

Comment: @AniMenon NAA flag should not be used for answer that do not correctly answer the question. That is the issue. Please go over the linked post which explains how it should be used.

Comment: @AniMenon highly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, its controversial but worth a delete vote since they don't answer the question, the answer just pointed out a possible issue & pointed at other answers.

Comment: @AniMenon I can get behind a delete vote.  I cannot get behind using the LQPQ as a substitute for delete votes for people who do not have them.  There is a reason deleting answers is a 20K priv.

Comment: @NathanOliver Agreed.

Answer (score 13):

> Its not an *attempt*, he is just telling what would happen, not how to fix it.

So it's not considered an attempt at an answer until it contains a fix? What if the question wasn't about a problem that needed fixing in the first place? Would you consider such questions off-topic then?

Sure, the answer doesn't seem to add much more than clutter given that answers from up to four days before had already provided the fixes that you allude to. In fact, if you notice, several of the answers that provide a fix don't provide any explanation of what's going on. If a complete answer provides both, then those answers are just as incomplete as this one in my books.

But even if you think providing a solution alone is enough to make a complete answer, that does not make an answer that provides an explanation *instead* any less of an answer to the question. Probably an incomplete answer, but it's not like the user was addressing a different question altogether (e.g. posting a Python answer to a PHP question).

Also, I almost never trust review comments. They're often wrong. A lot of reviewers seem to treat "This does not provide an answer to the question." to mean "This does not provide a *satisfactory* answer to the question." (and based on your assessment that this answer should be a comment you seem to think the same way). But that's simply not what it means. Just because someone left a review comment doesn't mean they are right.

Comment: Yes, its an answer only if it answers the question! (or atleast [directs the OP in the right direction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)).

Comment: So, let me ask you, how does that answer not answer the question, or not point the asker in the right direction (which is what, presumably, an explanation is supposed to do)?

Comment: Are you telling me his answer points the OP in the right direction? If yes, explain.

Comment: "You send a POST request that PHP cannot understand." So something was wrong with the way the asker was sending the request, i.e. it wasn't an issue with PHP but an issue with the Ajax request. For a savvy reader, that alone would have been enough for them to figure out a solution and maybe post a more complete answer. But even if it didn't point readers in the *right* direction, at least the answerer *tried*.

Comment: It doesn't point the user in the right direction. Well I do agree user *tried* but it should be a comment plus you can see that it has be recommended for deletion by all the reviewers. Why wasn't any action taken?

Comment: That's a separate question that I cannot answer because I'm not intimately familiar with how the review process plays out. The review is for Low Quality Posts - evidently the reviewers thought the answer was low quality and should just go away. That's not what you're trying to argue for, though. You're saying this isn't even an answer to begin with.

Comment: The user has **tried** but has not given an answer to the OP's question. That's the reason I said, *It could be a comment* but not an answer(its a low-quality/bad answer if you consider it an answer).

Answer (score -3):

Six deletion flags were required hence the answer wasn't deleted earlier.

**Flag and wait** for the others to recommend delete. That's how that answer finally got deleted.

5 recommended deletes & 3 deletion votes, and finally that "low-quality" answer was gone.